# How can I use MultiRNNCell with cell= ConvLSTMCell?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

How can I build a multi-layer neural network with the different number of filters in each layer with cell = ConvLSTMCell() and MultiRNNCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell_1 = ConvLSTMCell(...params...)
cell_2 = ConvLSTMCell(...params...)

multi_cell = MultiRNNCell([cell_1, cell_2], ...other params...)
```

Then you can call tensorflow `dynamic_rnn(..)` api with `multi_cell` and required parameters.

Comment: What about the decoder part? I am using "tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder" for the decoding part. @amin__